# Large amount of errors regarding "IServiceProvider"

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2017, c++-cli

Strange issue...

This is using VisualStudio Community 2017 and is a C++CLI WinForms project.

**BGStatsInterface.cpp**

```
#include "BGStatsInterface.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

[STAThreadAttribute]
void Main(array<String^>^ args) {
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    BattlegroundStats::BGStatsInterface form;
    Application::Run(%form);

}
```

**BGStatsInterface.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <windows.h>
#include "LuaReader.h"


namespace BattlegroundStats {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;
    using namespace System::IO;

    public ref class BGStatsInterface : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        BGStatsInterface(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this->MinimizeBox = false;
            this->MaximizeBox = false;
        }

        static System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBoxLog;
        static System::Void addMsg(String^ text) {
            textBoxLog->AppendText(text + "\n");
        }

    protected:
        ~BGStatsInterface()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }

    private: LuaReader ^ reader = gcnew LuaReader();
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  b1;

    private:
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code

        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->textBoxLog = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->b1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // textBoxLog
            // 
            this->textBoxLog->BackColor = System::Drawing::SystemColors::ControlLightLight;
            this->textBoxLog->Cursor = System::Windows::Forms::Cursors::IBeam;
            this->textBoxLog->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 6.75F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point,
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->textBoxLog->Location = System::Drawing::Point(10, 80);
            this->textBoxLog->Multiline = true;
            this->textBoxLog->Name = L"textBoxLog";
            this->textBoxLog->ReadOnly = true;
            this->textBoxLog->ScrollBars = System::Windows::Forms::ScrollBars::Vertical;
            this->textBoxLog->Size = System::Drawing::Size(280, 90);
            this->textBoxLog->TabIndex = 6;
            this->textBoxLog->TabStop = false;
            this->textBoxLog->GotFocus += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &BGStatsInterface::textBoxLog_HideCaret);
            // 
            // b1
            // 
            this->b1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(100, 30);
            this->b1->Name = L"b1";
            this->b1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
            this->b1->TabIndex = 7;
            this->b1->Text = L"DoSomething";
            this->b1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->b1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &BGStatsInterface::b1_Click);
            // 
            // BGStatsInterface
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(301, 411);
            this->Controls->Add(this->b1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBoxLog);
            this->FormBorderStyle = System::Windows::Forms::FormBorderStyle::FixedSingle;
            this->MaximumSize = System::Drawing::Size(317, 450);
            this->MinimumSize = System::Drawing::Size(317, 450);
            this->Name = L"BGStatsInterface";
            this->Text = L"Test";
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();
        }
#pragma endregion

        System::Void textBoxLog_HideCaret(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
            TextBox^ focus = safe_cast<TextBox^>(sender);
            HideCaret((HWND)focus->Handle.ToPointer());
        }

        System::Void b1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
            reader->DoSomething();
            addMsg("DoingSomethingA");
            System::Diagnostics::Debug::WriteLine("DoingSomethingA");
        }
    };
}
```

**LuaReader.cpp**

```
#include "LuaReader.h"
#include "BGStatsInterface.h" // PointA- This is where I'm having the issue.

using namespace System;

LuaReader::LuaReader(){}
System::Void LuaReader::DoSomething() {
    BattlegroundStats::BGStatsInterface::addMsg("DoingSomethingB");
    System::Diagnostics::Debug::WriteLine("DoingSomethingB");
}
```

**LuaReader.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "GameCollection.h" // PointB - Another issue here.

ref class LuaReader
{

public:
    LuaReader();
    GameCollection^ gameData = gcnew GameCollection();
    System::String^ _fileName;
    System::Void DoSomething();
};

#endif
```

**GameCollection.cpp**

```
#include "GameCollection.h"
GameCollection::GameCollection(){}
```

**GameCollection.h**

```
#pragma once
using namespace System;

ref class GameCollection
{
public:
    GameCollection();
};
```

**The Problem:**

In LuaReader.cpp If I include BGStatsInterface.h (needed so it can access the addMsg method), noted by PointA, it wont compile and will generate the errors listed below.

However, if I remove the GameCollection.h include from LuaReader.h (needed so I can create the GameCollection object), noted at PointB, it has no issues with BGStatsInterface.h included in the LuaReader.cpp file and everything compiles/runs without issues.

I don't know what to do... Why does it only work if I don't create the GameCollection object in LuaReader.h?

What have I done wrong?

**Errors:**

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E1986   an ordinary pointer to a C++/CLI ref class or interface class is not allowed    BattlegroundStats   c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.16299.0\um\servprov.h   91  
Error (active)  E0266   "IServiceProvider" is ambiguous BattlegroundStats   c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.16299.0\um\servprov.h   115 
Error (active)  E0266   "IServiceProvider" is ambiguous BattlegroundStats   c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.16299.0\um\servprov.h   239 
Error (active)  E0266   "IServiceProvider" is ambiguous BattlegroundStats   c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.16299.0\um\servprov.h   249 
Error (active)  E0266   "IServiceProvider" is ambiguous BattlegroundStats   c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.16299.0\um\urlmon.h 6867    
Error (active)  E0266   "IServiceProvider" is ambiguous BattlegroundStats   c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.16299.0\um\urlmon.h 6869        
Error   C3699   '*': cannot use this indirection on type 'IServiceProvider' BattlegroundStats   c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um\servprov.h   91  
Error   C2371   'IServiceProvider': redefinition; different basic types BattlegroundStats   c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um\servprov.h   98  
Error   C2872   'IServiceProvider': ambiguous symbol    BattlegroundStats   c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um\servprov.h   115 
Error   C2872   'IServiceProvider': ambiguous symbol    BattlegroundStats   c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um\servprov.h   239 
Error   C2872   'IServiceProvider': ambiguous symbol    BattlegroundStats   c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um\servprov.h   249 
Error   C2872   'IServiceProvider': ambiguous symbol    BattlegroundStats   c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um\urlmon.h 6867    
Error   C2872   'IServiceProvider': ambiguous symbol    BattlegroundStats   c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um\urlmon.h 6869
```

Comment: Common accident when you #include Windows.h, it defines ::IServiceProvider.  And the framework has System::IServiceProvider, very different animal.  Which becomes ambiguous when there's a `using namespace System` in scope somewhere.  Like in that GameCollection.h include file.  using statements are pretty poisonous in .h files, either don't use them or put that declaration in a namespace (like you should) and put the using directives inside that namespace.  You have a good example of that in the auto-generated code in BGStatsInterface.h

Comment: @HansPassant Ah! Thank you. That works. Quick related question, should I be using a namespace for all classes?

Comment: Yes, the global namespace is the home for C declarations.

Comment: Thank you for your help! :) If you add it as a reply I'll tag it as the solution, I don't think I can tag a comment as a solution.

Comment: Just complete the Q+A yourself with what you've learned.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This happens when using #include Windows.h as it defines ::IServiceProvider while the framework has System::IServiceProvider, then when there's a using namespace System in scope somewhere it becomes ambiguous.

Solution is to simply put the delcarations in your own namespace.

Answer (score 5):

Just providing another solution in here if your project is small - remove:

```
using namespace System;
```

and use full type name in the code for System's class, e.g. `System::String^`.

Answer (score 3):

To fix this, put your include file (that has windows.h in it) before declaring your namespaces and/or using statements:

So:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;
```

instead of

```
using namespace System;

#include "stdafx.h"
```

Hat tip to http://www.windows-tech.info/17/fbe07cd4dfcac878.php